# How can I restrict IP addresses dynamically and release them after 24hrs for AWS s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-policies, s3-iam-policy

I want to restrict the IP address for some hours(say 24 hrs), for those who query to my AWS s3 bucket(public read only) for more than 100/second. As they might be spam and wanted to harm my business by increasing traffic and raising my AWS costing. So far I have not found any policy example to perform this. How can I restrict these type of IP addresses dynamically and release them after 24hrs?

Comment: I dont think so its possible dynamically because there is no metric undercloudwatch which ca help you identify request/second metric https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/metrics-dimensions.html#s3-request-cloudwatch-metrics

Comment: That should be possible if you put CloudFront in front of your S3 bucket and then deploy AWS WAF with a rate-limiting ACL. Then you're not talking about plain S3 though.

Comment: Related document: [AWS Best Practices for DDoS
Resiliency](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/Security/DDoS_White_Paper.pdf). The managed service answer is CloudFront and WAAF.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1):

There is no out of the box solution for this, however you can build one:

1. Enable `Server Access Logging` on the bucket, which will ensure that the requests made against the bucket are logged. These logs will be similar to the following [1]:

   ```
   79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET1 [06/Feb/2019:00:00:38 +0000] 192.0.2.3 79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be 3E57427F3EXAMPLE REST.GET.VERSIONING - "GET /DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET1?versioning HTTP/1.1" 200 - 113 - 7 - "-" "S3Console/0.4" - s9lzHYrFp76ZVxRcpX9+5cjAnEH2ROuNkd2BHfIa6UkFVdtjf5mKR3/eTPFvsiP/XV/VLi31234= SigV4 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 AuthHeader DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET1.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com TLSV1.2 arn:aws:s3:us-west-1:123456789012:accesspoint/example-AP Yes
   79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET1 [06/Feb/2019:00:00:38 +0000] 192.0.2.3 79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be 891CE47D2EXAMPLE REST.GET.LOGGING_STATUS - "GET /DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET1?logging HTTP/1.1" 200 - 242 - 11 - "-" "S3Console/0.4" - 9vKBE6vMhrNiWHZmb2L0mXOcqPGzQOI5XLnCtZNPxev+Hf+7tpT6sxDwDty4LHBUOZJG96N1234= SigV4 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 AuthHeader DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET1.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com TLSV1.2 - -
   79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET1 [06/Feb/2019:00:00:38 +0000] 192.0.2.3 79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be A1206F460EXAMPLE REST.GET.BUCKETPOLICY - "GET /DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET1?policy HTTP/1.1" 404 NoSuchBucketPolicy 297 - 38 - "-" "S3Console/0.4" - BNaBsXZQQDbssi6xMBdBU2sLt+Yf5kZDmeBUP35sFoKa3sLLeMC78iwEIWxs99CRUrbS4n11234= SigV4 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 AuthHeader DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET1.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com TLSV1.2 - Yes 
   79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET1 [06/Feb/2019:00:01:00 +0000] 192.0.2.3 79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be 7B4A0FABBEXAMPLE REST.GET.VERSIONING - "GET /DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET1?versioning HTTP/1.1" 200 - 113 - 33 - "-" "S3Console/0.4" - Ke1bUcazaN1jWuUlPJaxF64cQVpUEhoZKEG/hmy/gijN/I1DeWqDfFvnpybfEseEME/u7ME1234= SigV4 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 AuthHeader DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET1.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com TLSV1.2 - -
   79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET1 [06/Feb/2019:00:01:57 +0000] 192.0.2.3 79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be DD6CC733AEXAMPLE REST.PUT.OBJECT s3-dg.pdf "PUT /DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET1/s3-dg.pdf HTTP/1.1" 200 - - 4406583 41754 28 "-" "S3Console/0.4" - 10S62Zv81kBW7BB6SX4XJ48o6kpcl6LPwEoizZQQxJd5qDSCTLX0TgS37kYUBKQW3+bPdrg1234= SigV4 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA AuthHeader DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET1.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com TLSV1.2 - Yes
   ```

   so they will include the IP address of the requester(s)
2. Create a dynamoDB table
3. Periodically, triggered by a schedule-based EventBridge rule, execute a lambda function which parses the log files of the last n minutes. If a certain IP address is found to be making too many requests, have the lambda function add the IP to the dynamoDB table (together with a timestamp of the current time) and add/update the bucket policy for the bucket to restrict the IP [2], e.g.:

   ```
   {
     "Id": "SourceIP",
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Statement": [
       {
         "Sid": "SourceIP",
         "Action": "s3:*",
         "Effect": "Deny",
         "Resource": [
           "arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET",
           "arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*"
         ],
         "Condition": {
           "IpAddress": {
             "aws:SourceIp": [
               "11.11.11.11/32",
               "22.22.22.22/32"
             ]
           }
         },
         "Principal": "*"
       }
     ]
   }
   ```
4. Periodically, triggered by a schedule-based EventBridge rule, execute another lambda function which reads from the dynamoDB table and checks whether for any of the offending IPs within it, 24 hrs have passed. If they have, remove their IP from the bucket policy.

---

References:

[1] : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/LogFormat.html

[2] : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_aws_deny-ip.html